# cout skipping the numbers after the decimal spaces

Tags: c++

I have assigned an `integer` to a `double` variable, but `cout` prints the double variable as an `int`. not as `double` . If I introduce  `cout << showpoint;` in the code then I m able to see the decimal values at the out put . Why is it so in the first case ? Here is the code .

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>

T sum(T a,T b)
{
  T retval; 
  retval=a+b;
  return retval;
}

int main()
{
  double a,x;
  float y,v=4.66;
  int z(3);   
  x=z;
  y=(double)z;   
  a=sum(5,6);

  //cout << showpoint;

  cout<<"The value of a is : "<<a<<endl; 
  cout<<"The value of x is : "<<x<<endl;   
  cout<<"The value of y is : "<<y<<endl;
}
```

The output in first case is

```
The value of a is : 11
The value of x is : 3
The value of y is : 3
```

The output after enabling `cout<<showpoint` in the second case is

```
The value of a is : 11.0000
The value of x is : 3.00000
The value of y is : 3.00000
```

Comment: setprecision is not present, i have edited the question

Comment: what is `showpoint` ?

Comment: @Raxvan : here's the link where you can get the answer http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/c241man/node83.html

Comment: @Raxvan: One of the standard manipulators from `<iomanip>`, which does exactly what the question describes.

Comment: @Mike Seymour i see now , i have not seen it before that's why i was asking. It says in the doc http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpoint/ that that's the intended behavior

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, floating point types are only displayed with a decimal point if they need one. If they have an integer value, they are displayed without one.

As you found, you can change this behaviour with `showpoint` (and change it back with `noshowpoint`), if you want.

Comment: if i say double var = 3.6787 and say cout<<var it gets printed as 3.6787 the numbers after the point are not skipped .but why when an integer is assigned to a double this happens ?

Comment: @blitz: Because that's how many people expect an integer value to be displayed, so that's how the library designers decided it should behave by default. If you don't like the default behaviour, use `showpoint` to change it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The default output format is a compromise; like most compromises, it does nothing particularly well, but it is acceptable (i.e. comfortable for "normal" values, but not excessively long regardless of the value) in a lot of quicky code, or for debugging.  As for `showpoint`, it's there because C has `%#g`; I can't think of a case where I'd actually use it.  If I'm concerned about the format, I'll use `fixed` or `scientific`, and go on from there.  (`showpoint` affects the output the way its name indicates for `fixed` or `scientific` if the precision is 0.)

Comment: With regards to changing it back, a much better strategy is to save all of the format information before modifying it, and then restore it.  Depending on the context, this can be done in the destructor of the manipulator you write, or using an RAII class around the code which modifies the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be in the same link posted by you. Just that cpp standards (i mean std streams) have the printing of trailing zeros disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental reason is only because that's what the standard
says.  For historical reasons, C++ output formatting is defined
in terms of C and `printf` formatting.  By default, floating
point is output using the `%g` format, which is an adaptive
format, which changes according to the values involved, as well
as according to various formatting flags.  For similar
historical reasons: the default format will suppress trailing
zeros after the point, and if there are no digits after the
point, it will suppress the point as well.  If you specify
`showpoint`, the results are the equivalent of `%#g`, which not
only causes the point to be displayed, regardless, but also
causes trailing zeros to be displayed.

In practice, this default format is almost never what you want
for real program output; its only real use is for debugging, and
various "informational" output.  If you want fixed point, with
a fixed number of decimals after the point, you have to specify
it:

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
```

Normally, this will be done in some sort of hand written
manipulator, so that the format for a specific semantic value is
specified once (in the manipulator), and then you use the
manipulator to specify the signification of the value to be
output, something like:

```
std::cout << weight << someWeight;
```

For quick, throw away code, it's often convenient to have some
sort of generic specifiers as well; I've got something like:

```
class FFmt
{
    int myWidth;
    int myPrecision;
public:
    FFmt( int width, int precision = 6 )
        : myWidth( width )
        , myPrecision( precision )
    {
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& dest, FFmt const& fmt )
    {
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
        dest.precision( myPrecision );
        dest.setw( myWidth );
        return dest;
    }
};
```

(Actually, my version is more complex, because it derives from
a base class which saves the current formatting options in the
`<<` operator, and restores them in the destructor; since such
classes are used almost exclusively as temporaries, this means
at the end of the full expression.)

This supports writing things like:

```
std::cout << FFmt( 9, 6 ) << x;
```

Not something you'd want in production code (since you don't want to
specify the format at the point you're outputting the data), but
quite useful for quick, one time programs.